# How do I paste an emoji in notepad++ without it turning to "??"

Tags: notepad++

It was working yesterday but I don't recall changing anything.
When I try to paste "" in notepad++, it simply turns to "??". 
Any ideas how I can fix it? cheers

Answer (score 13):

The "Use DirectWrite" setting might be what you're looking for.

Click on "Settings" and then select "Preferences...", the options to the left select "MISC" and turn on "Use DirectWrite".

[image]

Comment: My Notepad++ in Win 10 (v7.2.2 64-bit) does not have this "Use DirectWrite" option in MISC. Ah, Notepad++ v8.5.8 x64 at https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v8.5.8/ does have that option. And it improves the rendering of most of these, but not all of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580013/how-do-i-paste-an-emoji-in-notepad-without-it-turning-to#comment136540102_56671646

Answer (score 1):

Your encoding is probably set to `ANSI`. Because the ANSI character set does not include any emojis, they are shown as `??`. You want to change your encoding to `UTF-8`. I'm pretty sure UTF-8 is the default. Your encoding settings must have changed since yesterday.

To permanently change it, go:

*Settings -> Preferences... -> New Document*

and make sure `UTF-8` or `UTF-8 with BOM` is selected.

[image: Set UTF-8 as the encoding for new documents to use emojis]

Also, you can change the encoding of an individual document by going:

*Encoding -> Encode to UTF-8*

[image: Use the Encoding menu to change the encoding of the current document]

If you want to know more about character encodings, watch this excellent video by Computerphile/Tom Scott - *Characters, Symbols and the Unicode Miracle* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4

Comment: I've tried both, and neither worked for most of these: ➔➜➡➞➙➢➣➤➧➪➩▷›˃≻▸➡️►◄▲▼✅✔✓✗✘❌❎•·○◦°⦾⦿◘◘◙●⬤❍✸✽Ⓝ⋈ⓥⓋ1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣8️⃣9️⃣